# Happy 4th anniversary, MathOverflow!

Tags: discussion

As some will cerainly know today (September 28th) is MO's anniversary, its fourth to be precise. Since this year it appears there is no system-message to celebrate the event, I thought I create this meta question to celebrate.

Thanks to the fellow community members and especially the moderators for making this an interesting and fun place to contribute.

If you feel like it, share some story, make some wild guesses about MO's future, sing a song, or whatever comes to mind.

Comment: Here's a song you might sing: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2VZbWJIndlQ

Comment: Happy birthday, MO.  Thanks to Anton and all the moderators for making MO a good resource for mathematics and a fun place as well.

Comment: Perhaps we could crowd source a rewrite of "Lobachevsky" for MathOverflow. "And who deserves the credit?  And who deserves the blame?  Antonin Ivanovish Geraschenko is (not) his name!", as well as "The secret of my success?  Hyperlink!"  (Rhyme forthcoming.)

Comment: Wink, wink :-)${}$